# camel cxf more than one path param error

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

I am using camel cxfrs component to expose rest webservices. the interface below work fine with one @PathParam parameter.

```
public interface Service2 {
    @GET
    @Path("/world2/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response hello2(@PathParam("id") String id) ;
```

However if I add one more @Pathparam annotated parameter than it throws the exception below. Any idea about what is the problem here or how to solve it?

```
public interface Service2 {
    @GET
    @Path("/world2/{id}/{id2}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response hello2(@PathParam("id") String id,@PathParam("id2") String id2 ) ;
```

The exception :

```
2017-07-24 14:24:33.725  WARN 7840 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper  : javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toInternalServerErrorException(SpecExceptions.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toInternalServerErrorException(ExceptionUtils.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.convertExceptionToResponseIfPossible(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:189)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:315)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:304)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:288)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider.readFrom(StringTextProvider.java:45)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider.readFrom(StringTextProvider.java:36)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1352)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1303)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:829)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:793)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:212)
    ... 49 more
```

And my route is basic for test purpose :

```
CxfRsEndpoint serviceEndpoint = new CxfRsEndpoint("/rest2", cxfComponent);
        serviceEndpoint.addResourceClass(Service2.class);
        serviceEndpoint.setProviders(providers);
        serviceEndpoint.setSynchronous(true);
        serviceEndpoint.setAddress("/rest2");
        serviceEndpoint.setBus(bus);
        serviceEndpoint.getFeatures().add(swagger2Feature);

        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder(camelContext) {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(serviceEndpoint)
                .id(Service2.class.getCanonicalName()+"rest")   
                .log("${header.operationName} message here")
            }
```

Comment: What version of CXF and Camel are you using? And have you tried using a newer version

Comment: Camel version 2.19.1,cxf version, 3.1.12, spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE.

Comment: The stacktrace seems to indicate its a CXF bug/issue. Maybe you can try building a pure JAX-RS example with just CXF and Spring-Boot that has 2 path-param and see what it does.

Comment: I tried it actually, with pure jaxrs its working.With only one param case camel-cxf also working, when I add another param this error occurs. I can upload my code to github if you want to check.

Comment: Yes that would be good